# how to create custom calendar for both iphone and ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, calendar, custom-controls

how to create custom calendar for both iphone and ipad ,in that also we can add image to calendar tile(date cell)corresponding to image created date(created date will be get from image meta data).Am search in cococontrol also they didn`t provide like these calendar type model

Comment: Check this demo . and try to implement adding custom image in date.https://github.com/tjeerdintveen/Vurig-Calendar/blob/master/Vurig%20Calendar/VRGCalendarView.h

Comment: In kal calendar am implement this but its UI not cachive

Comment: 3 years old post. But you can try [this one](https://cocoapods.org/pods/JTAppleCalendar). The best i know of.